# Can not add query params to the nextjs dynamic route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have file named. `[slug].js`.

what I am trying to do is that I want to add query parameter to this dynamic route, this is the code.

```
   await router.replace({
          pathname: `${router.pathname}`,
          query: { coupon },
        },
        undefined,
        { shallow: true });
```

This works fine every static page but on dynamic page it gives me this error:

```
Error: The provided `href` (/home/[slug]?theme=dark) value is missing query values (slug) to be interpolated properly. Read more: https://err.sh/vercel/next.js/href-interpolation-failed
```

any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `router.asPath` to get current page path without query string  :

```
router.replace({
          pathname: router.asPath,
          query: { coupon },
        },
        undefined,
        { shallow: true });
```

Answer (score 4):

@Ghader's answer in in the correct direction, but incomplete:

```
router.replace(
  {
    pathname: router.asPath.split('?')[0],
    query: { coupon },
  },
  undefined,
  { shallow: true }
);
```

You need to remove query parameters from the `pathname` as otherwise, you are going to get double encoded URLs.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just adding query parameters to the current path, you can completely omit the `pathname` field from the URL object.

```js
router.replace(
    { query: { coupon } },
    undefined,
    { shallow: true }
);
```